# Fail to parse xml in php (redirect issue?)

Tags: php, xml, rss

I'm trying to extract the content of a feed but my code fail on this feed:
http://legaltalknetwork.com/RSS/WCM_feed.xml
The feed redirects to http://wcm.ltn.libsynpro.com/rss

If I use the final feed url in my code it work fine, but I need to make it work with the original url: http://legaltalknetwork.com/RSS/WCM_feed.xml

Here's my code:

```
  $curl_handle=curl_init();
  curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
  curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla');
  curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 15);
  curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
  curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
  curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);

  $xml = simplexml_load_string(curl_exec($curl_handle));
  curl_close($curl_handle);
```

Which returns null...
Any idea how to solve this ?

Comment: @PHPGlue ...who cares why he doesn't want to? He said he doesn't. The `curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);` means he shouldn't need to. @user1026605 I tested your code, it returns valid XML and it's parsed correctly. Break your `curl_exec()` out into its own variable and echo that out before assuming it's valid XML.

Comment: curl_exec($curl_handle) returns false with the original url...

Is the following code working for you ?

   $curl_handle=curl_init();
   curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://legaltalknetwork.com/RSS/WCM_feed.xml');
   $curlResult = curl_exec($curl_handle);

if ($curlResult === false) {
echo "KO";
}

Comment: In fact it looks like it always timeout. If I open the page in a web browser it loads really fast. If I increase the timeout to 5 minutes it still timeout...